# Recover deleted SMS message using Google Backup?

Tags: sms, data-recovery, sony-xperia, google-backup

I use Android 4.4.4 & XPeria Z3. Google auto backup service is turned on.

Recently I deleted my SMS messages and now I want to recover one particular SMS.

Is it possible via Google Backup? If yes, what is the correct way?